# Magento Observer to add order grid column - ambiguous issue

Tags: magento, join, magento-1.7

I have fix the problem, FINALLY!

Basically I'm getting WHERE part with `$where = $select->getPart('where')` and then I go through each condition and searching for `created_at`, If I find matching then I replace `created_at` with `main_table.created_at`.

I've tested this, and everything works fine, if there is something that can be "buggy" please let me know.

Thanks all!!

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{

  $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
  $select     = $collection->getSelect();
  $select->joinLeft(array('custab' => 'my_custom_table'), 'main_table.entity_id = custab.order_id',array('custab.field_to_show_in_grid'));

  if ($where = $select->getPart('where')) {
      foreach ($where as $key=> $condition) {
          if (strpos($condition, 'created_at')) {
              $new_condition = str_replace("created_at", "main_table.created_at", $condition);
              $where[$key] = $new_condition;
          }
      }
      $select->setPart('where', $where);
  }
```

}

I'm trying to add new column in sales order grid from custom table using observer. Everything works fine until I try to filter grid using column `created_at`.

Problem is because I have same column name (`created_at`) in custom table and in `sales_flat_order_grid` table.

I'm getting this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

If I edit this line `'index' => 'created_at'`
 to
 `'index' => '**main_table**.created_at'`, in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));
```

everything work fine, but I don't want to change core files or to copy them to local folder and edit, I think that there is some simple solution that I need to add to my observer.

Here is my Observer.php

```
class Testinggrid_ExtendOrderGrid_Model_Observer{
    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
       $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
       $select     = $collection->getSelect();
       $select->joinLeft(array('custab' => 'my_custom_table'), 'main_table.entity_id = custab.order_id',array('custab.field_to_show_in_grid'));
    }
}
```

Here is my module layout

```
<layout>
  <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <action method="addColumnAfter">
            <columnId>field_to_show_in_grid</columnId>
            <arguments>
                <header>Column header</header>
                <index>field_to_show_in_grid</index>
                <filter_index>field_to_show_in_grid</filter_index>
                <type>text</type>
            </arguments>
            <after>shipping_name</after>
        </action>
    </reference>
  </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
  <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
    <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
  </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
  <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <!-- apply layout handle defined above -->
    <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
  </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: I have been using the solution for quite some time, but recently it caused an error when I filtered my order grid: `Unknown column 'main_table.created_at' in 'where clause'`. My solution was to change `str_replace("created_at", "main_table.created_at", $condition);` to `str_replace("\`created_at\`", "\`main_table\`.created_at", $condition);` (notice the added grave (\`) characters).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It worked for me. Voted up

Answer (score 4):

After lots of research, I've come up with various solutions to this problem, non of which seem ideal, but someone might be able to improve on one of them.

First, the why of the problem. Before you do your join, Magento has already prepared a portion of the query, represented as objects. This portion set ups the 'select' and and "where's" that need to be done for filtering, it will result in a query that will look something like:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid`
WHERE (`grand_total` <= '20')
```

The problem is the 'where' part of the query, as the column names are not prefixed with the table name alias `main_table`. If you then try to extend this query by adding a join to a table that has a column with the same name as **any** column in the where clause, you'll get the 'ambiguous' error. For example if you were to join the above query to the `sales_flat_order` table, then it would fail as that table also has a `grand_total` column, making the 'where' clause in the filter ambiguous.

Magento has a mechanism to deal with just this problem, the `filterIndex`. Column objects which form the the grid can have a filter index set, using

```
$column = $block->getColumn('grand_total');
$column->setFilterIndex('main_table.grand_total');
```

Which would adjust the 'where' clause in the above query to `` WHERE `main_table`.`grand_total` <= '20' ``

Which would solve all the problems if we were able to get at the `$column` object before the SQL has actually been prepared.

### Solutions

1. **Override the core files**

Override and subclass `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class. Only override the the `_prepareColumns()` method like so:

```
class Mycomp_Mymodule_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        //get the columns from the parent so they can be returned as expected
        $columns = parent::_prepareColumns();
        $this->addColumnAfter('custom_column', array(
            'header'    => 'Custom Column',
            'index'     => 'custom_column',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'filter_index'=> 'custom_table.custom_column',
        ), 'billing_name' );
        //columns need to be reordered
        $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
        return $columns;
    }
}
```

2. **Rewrite the query before its executed**

This is the solution shown in the question, where you grab the 'where' clause and then do some sort of find and replace to add in the `main_table` prefix. Something like

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();    
$where = $select->getPart('where');
//find an replace each element in the where array
```

3. **Use a subquery in your 'join' clause**

As the problem is caused by a column with the same name in both tables, its possible to change the 'join' query to rename or remove the ambiguous column. Adjusting the join clause to:

```
$subquery = new Zend_Db_Expr( 
    '(SELECT order_id AS order_alias, 
             field_to_show_in_grid AS field_to_show_in_grid_alias
      FROM my_custom_table)');
$select->joinLeft( array('custab' => $subquery), 
                   'main_table.entity_id = custab.order_alias',
                   array('custab.field_to_show_in_grid_alias'));
```

Whilst this does work, the query is too slow to be practical.
The query can be modified to speed it up like so:

```
$subquery = new Zend_Db_Expr( 
    '(SELECT field_to_show_in_grid
      FROM my_custom_table
      WHERE main_table.entity_id=my_custom_table.order_id)');
$select->addFieldToSelect( array('field_to_show_in_grid_alias'=>$subquery) );
```

Whilst this works and is quick, the problem is that Magento uses the objects that make up this query twice, once for the grid itself and also in a 'count' to generate the pagination wigits at the top of the grid page. Unfortunately, when used in the 'count' query, Magento does not use the selected columns, only the 'from', 'join' and 'where' portions of the query. This means that if you use the above query, you can't filter on the new column you are adding.

4. **Add column to the sales_flat_order_grid**

The sales_flat_order_grid table can be extended to include the extra column you require and have that column automatically updated. This technique is described here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4626/34327

5. **Intercept and add the filter index before the query is built**

There is an event which can be intercepted, interrogated and altered before the SQL has been fully prepared. This is `resource_get_tablename`, but you need to check that you are working with the correct table.

To get this working, I'd write an observer of the `resource_get_tablename` event as follows

```
public function resourceGetTablename(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //Check we are working with the correct table
    if( $observer->getTableName() == 'sales_flat_order_grid' ) {

        $block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('sales_order.grid');

        foreach( $block->getColumns() as $column ) {
            //create a filter index for each column using 'main_table' prefixed to the column index
            $column->setFilterIndex('main_table.' . $column->index);
        }

    }
}
```

I hope that someone can improve upon one of these methods to create something really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
<filter_index>field_to_show_in_grid</filter_index>
```

To

```
<filter_index>main_table.created_at</filter_index>
```

See [Adding a column to Magento orders grid - alternative way using layout handles](http://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/)

Comment: Hey R.S, if I change that, than I can't filter grid with new column, and ambiguous problem is still there. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you add the actual code (field names) instead of `field_to_show_in_grid`. In 'custab' do you have a field name 'created_at', did you try to remove it from the join or alas it using `array('custab.created_at'=>'custab_created_at')`

Comment: What's the difference if my column have some other name? I think that won't help...

Comment: Take a look at the query using `print_r($select->__toString());`

Comment: This is SQL Query before adding any filters 'SELECT `main_table`.*, `custab`.`field_to_show_in_grid` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `my_custom_table` AS `custab` ON main_table.entity_id = custab.order_id'
I dont know why created_at from 'my_custom_table' making problems, when that field isnt in query at all...

Comment: Because when you filter on `created_at`, MySQL does not know on which field you actually want to filter if it's not prefixed with the corresponding table alias, as two query tables have a field with the same name. Having selected one or not is not taken into account at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$collection->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');` in your observer

Comment: Hey blmage, thanks for your answer but that isn't fixed my problem. I got same error( I have cleared cache, both magento and browser)

Comment: In fact I think that the event you observe (`sales_order_grid_collection_load_before`) is dispatched too late, in your case `addFilterToMap()`  would only be useful when applied before `addFieldToFilter()` is called, what's not the case. If you still want to use the layout method, then you'll have to add another observer on a more generic event such as `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`, and add the call to `addFilterToMap()` in it.

Comment: I've tried that but with no luck, observer won't "fire" when I'm on orders grid

Comment: Yes, actually after verification `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` is called too early... In fact, there is no observable event between the moment when the collection is prepared (then initialized), and the moment when the filters are added to it, as everything is done in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection()`.You'll either have to rewrite the orders grid, or to alter the collection select object in your first observer with `$collection()->getSelect()->(g|s)etPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE)`, when you detect that `created_at` is present